# Is there any delegate methods to detect when ever the scene changes in storyboard in ios application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know one way of doing this.That is "viewDidLoad" will be called when ever the scene changes. Is there any other way to detect when ever the scene changes in storyboard because i want to call one method when ever the scene changes. I am developing SDK for ios application i can not ask application developer to call methods on every scene(I want to improve it), so i want to detect automatically when the scene changes and call my method there instead.Please help guys i am trying to do this from so many days but no could not find anything about it.

Comment: is there any confusion with the question. Please let me know i will change it if any part of question is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do, is to swizzle UIKit's `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` method,
So you need to do 3 steps

1. Catch `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` call
2. Call original `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` method
3. Do you initialization stuff.

Here is a complete solution of your problem

1) Crate category named "Initialization" on UIViewController class
 2) Copy below code
 3) Insert you initialization code at `// Your init here`

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (Initialization)

+ (void)load
{
    swizzleInstance(@selector(viewDidLoad),
                    @selector(viewDidLoad_m),
                    [UIViewController class],
                    [self class]);
}

static void swizzleInstance(SEL originalSl, SEL swizzledSl, Class originalCl, Class swizzledCl) {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalCl, originalSl);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(swizzledCl, swizzledSl);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad_m
{
    [self viewDidLoad_m];

    // Your init here
}
```

Comment: i Don't know which type of controller developer of application is using,Actually I wont know anything about application priorly. I am developing SDK for application but not application. I want to call one method inside SDK when ever the scene changes.

Comment: @veteranHero did you try to run this code before commenting?

Comment: I'm saying to swizzle the `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]`, you are commenting that you don't know class names of SDK user, read answer again!

Answer (score -1):

viewDidLoad is only called the FIRST time a view is displayed. If you keep the view controller around and then return to it then it won't be called again. (With Storyboards most people simply discard a view controller when the user closes it and then recreate it upon return, so this may not be an issue, but it is important to be aware of it.)

I would advise against method swizzling as advised by the other poster.

Instead you might think about creating a custom base class for all your view controllers. In that base class implement both viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods. In those methods you can broadcast a notification or send some other sort of message that will let you track the display/dismissal of your view controllers.

All view controllers that implement viewWillAppear:animated or viewWillDisappear:animated are supposed to call super, so the subclasses should still invoke the super version of those methods.

Answer (score -1):

`viewDidLoad` does not indicate that your scene has switched at all. Consider the following:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[myViewController.view addSubview:someView]; // viewDidLoad is called as a result of accessing the view property here
myViewController = nil; // the view controller is thrown away and the scene is never changed.
```

Instead, you should use `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear:`, and `viewDidDisappear:`. These are all methods that can be overridden by a `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: i Don't know which type of controller developer of application is using,Actually I wont know anything about application priorly. I am developing SDK for application but not application. I want to call one method inside SDK when ever the scene changes.

Comment: The `view*ppear` methods are called automatically by the system when a view that is controlled by a `UIViewController` (the base class of all view controllers) is made visible on the screen. If this does not answer your question, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ian MacDonald. This is what i am looking for. Actually I did not know that every controller(navigation controller,tab bar controller,table view controller)is being inherited from UIViewController.